# Compiling Environment on STM32 SDK isn't working

Tags: compiling, gcc, make

I'm following the following [tutorial](https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/Getting_started/STM32MP1_boards/STM32MP157x-EV1/Develop_on_Arm%C2%AE_Cortex%C2%AE-M4/Modify,_rebuild_and_reload_a_firmware) to setup an STM32MP157C-DK2 microcontroller. However, when I try to build the code, I receive the following error:

> make -j8 all
> arm-none-eabi-gcc -o "OpenAMP_TTY_echo_CM4.elf" @"objects.list"   -mcpu=cortex-m4 -T"/home/ben/STM32MPU_workspace/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v3.1.0/Developer-Package/STM32Cube_FW_MP1_V1.5.0/Projects/STM32MP157C-DK2/Applications/OpenAMP/OpenAMP_TTY_echo/STM32CubeIDE/CM4/STM32MP157CAAX_RAM.ld" --specs=nosys.specs -Wl,-Map="OpenAMP_TTY_echo_CM4.map" -Wl,--gc-sections -static --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group
> /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ./Application/Startup/startup_stm32mp157caax.o: in function `LoopFillZerobss': /home/ben/STM32MPU_workspace/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v3.1.0/Developer-Package/STM32Cube_FW_MP1_V1.5.0/Projects/STM32MP157C-DK2/Applications/OpenAMP/OpenAMP_TTY_echo/STM32CubeIDE/CM4/Application/Startup/startup_stm32mp157caax.s:90: undefined reference to` SystemInit'
> /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ./Application/User/main.o: in function `main':
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make: *** [makefile:63: OpenAMP_TTY_echo_CM4.elf] Error 1
> "make -j8 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

I abridged the error message, as there are actually about 82 of them, but they all have the general form of undefined references.

That is to say, there are really just 82 error messages like this:

```
undefined reference to 'BSP_LED_init'
```

Any ideas for what this might mean would be greatly appreciated. Not quite sure how to interpret or go about getting the build to go through. My guess is that it has something to do with properly setting the build environment/source, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: It looks like the SystemInit function should be provided by the target hardware vendor - see for example [System and Clock Configuration](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/cmsis/Core/html/group__system__init__gr.html#details)

Comment: @steeldriver I updated the question. I think the issue is with the build/make environment not recognizing all the references.